# Custom control events

Tags: c#, events, custom-controls

I've written a custom control which has a combo on there.

The combo has a SelectedIndexChanged event which has also been made visible to the application using the control.

So within the application I subscribe to the SelectedIndexChanged event too.

Within the application I change the combo value and the 2 events fire (I've tested this using message boxes).

All is great at this point, here is my problem: I have another control on my custom control which fires the SelectedIndexChanged event of the combo but the one within the application doesn't fire. How can I make this happen?

I hope that all makes sense?!

I'm using C# 4.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include code as to how you are making the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the `ComboBox` within your custom control visible outside the control? When the 2 events fire correctly from changing the value within the application, do you mean the change is made by the containing control/page via code, or the change is made by the user from the UI?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make a public function in your control that you can call from your application that fires the selectedIndexChanged event

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, I can do that but I don't really want that code within the application. The whole point of having the custom control is to remove the code from the application not have to call that same method every time I use the control.